# Retaining commas in journal titles with biblatex chem-angew style

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I have a number of entries in my bibliography of type:

```
journal = {J. Chem. Soc.{,} Perkin Trans. 1},
```

However the comma that follows the abbreviation dot is always stripped regardless of the additional braces. `\isdot` doesn't seem to be helpful when the punctuation  is mid entry nor does putting

```
\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*.?!}
```

in my `biblatex.cfg` file change anything.

Is there any way to suppress the punctuation removal for these entries?
Using MiKTeX 2.9 on windows 7 with:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, mcite,subentry,style=chem-angew, chaptertitle,sorting=none,sortcites=true backref=true]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is 'status bydesign': the style guide for *Angewandte Chemie* says that journal titles should not contain commas. You can disable the behaviour using

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{removecomma}{#1}
```

This works as the `removecomma` format is used by the style where it's required. Thus we can quickly turn it off by not applying the underlying function (`\mkbibnocomma`).

Comment: Thank you very much. Curiously, Angewandte guidelines say:  > Journal titles should be italicized and abbreviated in accordance with the "Chemical Abstracts Service Source Index" (CASSI; no commas appear in the journal names).  However CASSI itself includes the comma.

Comment: @dmca I didn't say they were particularly logical: I just to to follow what the editorial offices actually do!